# javaFX PopUp stays on top when window is hidden

Tags: javafx, popup, focus

My problem is that I want my popups to either close or not be stay-on-top.
Currently, when I click on a window which is different from my app, the app disappears behind it, but the popups stay on top, in front of the window belonging to a different application.

I want the popups to either behave differently, or as a hack I would like to hide the popup.

I tried to do this with Listeners as I found these in other q&a on stackoverflow, but these Listeners never get called when I minimize or lose focus with the window.

I commented out the code which does not work in below code.

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
 */
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    log.debug("JavaFx start method");
    //log.trace("is used", fileViewController.toString());
    try
    {

    splash.start(primaryStage, () -> startMain());
    primaryStage.toFront();

    //HACK attempt
    //primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);

    //FIXME: this doesn't work (is not called)
    /*
    primaryStage.iconifiedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
            System.err.println("minimized:" + t1.booleanValue());
            popupBuilder.hide();
            popupPicker.hide();
            popupAbout.hide();
            popupExecute.hide();
            popupAdministration.hide();
            popupLicensegenerator.hide();
            popupProjects.hide();
        }
    });
    */

    /*
     * This doesn't work, either
    primaryStage.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
             System.err.println("focus:" + newValue);
            if (!newValue){
                popupBuilder.hide();
                popupPicker.hide();
                popupAbout.hide();
                popupExecute.hide();
                popupAdministration.hide();
                popupLicensegenerator.hide();
                popupProjects.hide();
            }else{
                //nothing   
            }
        }

    });
     */
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log.error("Error during start initialization of main application!");
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
}
```

}

Comment: Ever find a good solution for this one?

Comment: No, sorry. I' on a different project right now.